# Dismiss keyboard for UIViewController which is down in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard

I have a tabbar app with 3 tabs (T1, T2, T3).

In T1 I have a navigation stack like this VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3. VC1 has textfield, a keyboard is shown for user input. After user input, I don't dismiss keyboard before user goes to VC2 and then to VC3.

Then user goes to T3, does something in T3 which is supposed to automatically switch her/him to T1 and VC1 directly.

When this happens VC1 in T1 shows keyboard. How can I dismiss keyboard in VC1 before it is on screen?

P.S. I obvoiusly tried `resignFirstResponder` and `[view endEditing:YES]` but it appears that they work properly only after VC1 is on screen (work in `viewDidAppear`, don't work in `viewWillAppear`).

EDIT1: Clarifications:

1. All view controllers are created programatically, there are no nib files or storyboards.
2. I could restructure navigation or try hiding keyboard before user goes into VC2 but I am interested in this particular question and not workarounds which involve changing logic of the app.
3. Dismissing keyboard works fine in `viewDidAppear` but user experience is not great.

Comment: why you just don't dismiss the keyboard when pushing T3?

Comment: @heximal As I said in clarifications, I am interested in fixing this without changing app logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're navigating, but try catching the transition in `prepareForSegue` or `unwindForSegue` or somewhere else that makes sense for you while in VC1.  Then dismissing the keyboard in one of the ways you've previously mentioned.

[UIViewController Doc prepareForSegue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:)

[UIViewController Doc unwindForSegue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/unwindForSegue:towardsViewController:)

Or even in `viewWillDisappear` or some other view event method of VC1

Comment: I could do that, but at the moment I don't want to change the logic of the app.